# Easiest way to expose existing data in secondary database as entities?

Tags: entities

Given a "node-like" database table in an "external" or "secondary" database, what's the easiest way to expose them as entities?

Documentation for the [entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module makes it seem easy for data stored in the local database, but I'm not sure how that can be translated to another db.

Comment: I assume you need proper fields so you can interact with the rest of Drupal?

Comment: I'll take what I can get :) If I can expose more data as fields, that's great.

Comment: Depending on where the external datasource is that might introduce a bit of a lag...could you just define or re-use an existing entity type and write something (e.g. a class for the migrate module) to sync entities on a schedule?

Comment: I'm currently looking at this video which promises to answer my question: http://blip.tv/drupalcondenver/drupalize-your-data-use-entities-6039543

Answer (score 2):

Some googling has revealed that the easiest solution is

1. Declare a new entity
2. Create a new Controller class for it that knows how/where to apply data operations.
3. Declare all your metadata as properties as opposed to fields.

I hope I'll be able to expand on this answer once I actually try it out. :)